# Android TextView requiresFadingEdge fade direction

Tags: android, textview

If I set `requiresFadingEdge="horizontal"` in my TextView with `gravity="right"`, the fading occurs at the left.

[image]

However, I want the fading to occur at the right end. I went through the documentation and couldn't find any attribute that I can set to control the fading direction. Is it possible?

Answer (score -1):

You can put

```
android:requiresFadingEdge="horizontal"
android:cacheColorHint="#000000"
android:textColor="#ffffff"
```

cacheColorHint will set the color for the fading edge

Comment: It's not working! I still get the fade at the left end. Can you explain which of these attributes is supposed to control the direction of fade? Thanks!

Comment: cacheColorHint will set the color for the fading edge